# Why we are going with more dimension if we can manage with single?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I observed for images we are creating a model with same number of dimensions but we have option to gray it out that change dimension from 3 to 1. For example :- if we have a color image of dimension (with RGB) 28x28x3, same we feed as input to our model. With the same image if we convert it to gray using rgb2gray method, that converts its dimension from 28x28x3 to 28x28. Why we are not feeding this grayed image always to our model?

Answer (score 0):

That approach depends on what you are trying to do. In some cases you need 3 channels in the image to achieve a better degree of precision. Since color is also information, smashing all the channels into a single channel discarts a lot of sometimes useful information. It is common to keep 3 channels in problems such as recognition of objects, segmentation, classification, etc. On the other hand gray scale is often used for document processing, HTR, OCR, etc.

One more thing: in Tensorflow you are going the need that last dimension, so if you want to use gray scaled images they must me shaped 28x28x1. Assuming you are using OpenCv you are gonna have to reshape the image before feeding it to the net.

Bare in mind that if the model was trained with gray images it won't work with color images for prediction!

I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on what you want to do...

If you want to train a model to discriminate between "Granny Smith" (green) and "Pink Lady" (red) apples, using greyscale images is not very helpful.

If you want to train a model to discriminate between apples and bananas, a greyscale image should be enough.